# Android distribute data in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm having difficulties when spreading the data I receive on the ListView

Assume I receive a list as:
list(String category, String name, String details, String isSection)
and I have

```
list.add("Drink", "Water", "Fresh Water", false)
list.add("Drink", "Cola", "8oZ", false)
list.add("Food", "Burger", "Homemade", false)
```

etc...

Now, when I call the adapter, the GetView method gets called. I implemented it as:

```
public class EntryRestaurantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RestaurantMenu> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<RestaurantMenu> items;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private static final int TYPE_SECTION = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 2;


    public EntryRestaurantAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<RestaurantMenu> items) {
        super(context,0, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount () {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).getSection() ? TYPE_SECTION : TYPE_ITEM;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final RestaurantMenu i = items.get(position);



        if (!i.getSection()){
            RestaurantMenu si = (RestaurantMenu)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

            v.setOnClickListener(null);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            v.setLongClickable(false);

            final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
            sectionView.setText(si.getCategory());

            for (int a=0; a<items.size(); a++){
//                if (items.indexOf(i.getCategory()) == items.lastIndexOf(i.getCategory()))
//                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
                if (i.getCategory().equals(items.get(a).getCategory())){
                    Log.d("Dentro del FOr ",""+ items.get(a).getSection());

                    items.get(a).setSection(true);
                    Log.d("Dentro del FOr despues del true ",""+ items.get(a).getSection());


                }
            }
        }
    else {

            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);

            TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name);
            RestaurantMenu si = (RestaurantMenu) i;
            sectionView.setText(si.getFoodName());
        }

        Log.d("Entry Section: ", "" + i.getSection() + " ID: " + i.getCategory());
        return v;
    }
```

I called on my main activity as:

```
 EntryRestaurantAdapter adapter = new EntryRestaurantAdapter(this, restaurantMenuList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works, but it omits the first one of each category. I think it happens because the getView method runs obviously ONCE for each position. This causes that it returns the v as a category and not as an item on the first try of each category. How can I fix this?

this is the output

Category: Drink
Item Cola  (it omitted the item view of water)
Category: Food (it omitted the item view of burger)

Comment: Can you post the entire adapter, and also the method where you define your list and adapter??

Comment: Sure thing. I will edit the post.

Comment: How many rows do you get in the list in total? In total i mean with items + sections

Comment: It really depends on the data im pulling. right now is about 4 rows each one with (category, name, details, isSection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, it just not possible to return two views at the same time. So, I just rearranged my list and made it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override these two methods in your Adapter:

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {...}
public int getItemViewType(int position) {...}
```

In the first one you should return how many types of view do you have in the list, and in the second one you should return the view type for the position, which could be any integer, something like this.

```
private static final int TYPE_SECTION = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 2;

....

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return items.get(position).getSection() ? TYPE_SECTION : TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

By the way, you are not reusing the view got in the convertView, but always create a new one which is bad for both the performance and the memory.

Comment: Hm, that didnt seemed to do anything. Anything else I should add? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eii Amigo,

I see that you are trying to create a list with sections. I have a [blogpost](http://www.iyildirim.com/tech-blog/creating-listview-with-sections) on my page on how to achieve this. There you can also access the project from github.

But there might be some problems with what you are doing.

- The array adapter will inflate the views depending on the items that is on the array. That means for example if the array is not sorted it will print it in random order. (I don't know if you already have thought about that issue)

Comment: They are printing just fine. The only problem is that I loose one item because it is taken as a category. It is, but is also an item.